# Problem with difference between two value in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

i'm starting learning python and during an analysis i need to computer every value in a column with any other value in the same column with 100005 entry. I was thinking about using a code like this:

```
for ts in u.trajectory:
  distanza5=distance_array(coppia5.positions, coppia5.positions)
  k=pd.DataFrame(distanza5)
  valore=k.iat[0,1]
  list.append(valore)
```

step1 = pd.concat([dist1,dist2], axis=1)

step2 = pd.concat([step1,dist3], axis=1)

step3 = pd.concat([step2,dist4], axis=1)

step4 = pd.concat([step3,dist5], axis=1)

```
 for i in step4.index:
   first=step4.iat[i,0]  
   y=abs(first)
   for n in range (0,100004):
     x=abs(step4.iat[n,0])
     value[n]=y-x
     list.append(value[n])
   diff[i]=pd.DataFrame(list)
   del list
```

But when i try to run it i get this error:
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment

The problem is given from the value[n] line.What can i do?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you post more of your code? One cause could be the initialization of the value variable, initially a float and not a list

Comment: @trolloldem i added few lines to show where i get these value from and how i generated step4 dataframe

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your code, the problem seems to be caused by the initialization of your **value** variable. This variable probably is initialized as a single float, for example by writing `value = k.iat[0,1]`. In order as intended you have to use a list or some indexable data structure. For example you can get rid of the **value** variable as shown in the following code:

```
 for i in step4.index:
   first=step4.iat[i,0]  
   y=abs(first)
   list = []
   for n in range (0,100004):
     x=abs(step4.iat[n,0])
     list.append(y-x)
   diff[i]=pd.DataFrame(list)
```

To solve the declaration problem of the diff variable, you can add this line `diff = pd.DataFrame()` before the `for i in step4.index` line and also change the last line of the code in this way:

```
diff = pd.DataFrame()
for i in step4.index:
   first=step4.iat[i,0]  
   y=abs(first)
   list = []
   for n in range (0,100004):
     x=abs(step4.iat[n,0])
     list.append(y-x)
   diff.loc[:,i] = pd.Series(list)
```

This new last line adds the entire list in a new column inside the diff dataframe created

Comment: may i ask you another thing? When i try to run it, it shows me an error because diff[i] is not define. Should i write a definition for it or how can i store the data i get from list? (btw i'm from Brescia too)

Comment: @user14002060 I've added some code to answer your question (btw: the world is small, I'm happy to help a near fellow)